# Why does Apple think I'm serving ads?

Tags: ios, cordova, google-analytics

Working with a Cordova app that we just added Google Analytics.  The Google advertising flag is being left at the default "NO" setting.  However, when I try to submit the app to Apple, it's saying that it's detecting IDFA and it asks me to specify what type of advertising we're doing.  The problem is that we're not doing any advertising, so there's no valid option for me to select.  Hence, I can't update the app.

Is there something that we've missed to setup just analytics without advertising?

Comment: When you create a new version for your app there is a checkbox that says something about using an advertising identifier, maybe you accidentally clicked that when you created the new version.  If so then you will have to create a new version again without clicking that checkbox.

Comment: What happened is I clicked "no" there like I usually do and Apple said nope, you're wrong, and says I need to take the "yes" route because I'm using IDFA (which I certainly don't mean to be using).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been a problem with [google-analytics-plugin](https://github.com/danwilson/google-analytics-plugin/issues/218) since the [AdSupport framework was added](https://github.com/danwilson/google-analytics-plugin/blob/master/plugin.xml#L48) by [this commit](https://github.com/danwilson/google-analytics-plugin/commit/bd3e2bbcdde803b088cfcaa5b4c40a9475010133).

The quickest workaround is to use the fork at https://github.com/kju-digital-solutions/google-analytics-plugin:

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/kju-digital-solutions/google-analytics-plugin
```

which [removes the ad framework](https://github.com/kju-digital-solutions/google-analytics-plugin/commit/3ebb629c01f9f0e8ebfceff5513be448154b4120#diff-53f390d375398624afe1cfe1125f42bf)